# Total transform of an effective Cartier divisor in blow-up, Vakil's Ex 22.4.P

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a scheme (assume it is Noetherian if necessary) and $p$ is a closed point whose sheaf of ideals is of finite type, then the blow up of $X$ along $p$, $\text{Bl}_p X$, exists and could be constructed in usual way. If $D$ is an effective Cartier divisor on $X$ that passes $p$, then $\text{mult}_p ~D$ could be defined as follows,

Locally around $p$, $D$ is cut out by a single function $f$ that is not a zero divisor, then  $\text{mult}_p ~D$ is defined as the largest number $d$ such that $f \in m_{X,p}^n$ but $f \notin m_{X,p}^{n+1}$

Let $D^{pr}$ be the proper transform of $D$ in the blow-up $\pi:\text{Bl}_p~X \rightarrow X$, is it true in this general setting that
\begin{equation}
\pi^*D=D^{pr}+(\text{mult}_pD)E
\end{equation} 
i.e. the local equation for $\pi*D$ is the product of the local equation of $D^{pr}$ and $\text{mult}_pD$ power of the local equation for $E$. This is certainly true when $X$ is a $k$-variety. How to prove this?